# Importing a filter variable from one Component to Another Component in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have these 2 components:

First One MAIN PAGE
`

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Navbar from "./navbar";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import '../styles/home.css'
import FavoriteCrypto from "./favoriteCrypto";
export default function MainPage() {

    const[data, setData] = useState([])
    const[input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false)
    const [modalArr, setModalArr] = useState([])
    const[favorites, setFavorites] = useState([])
    const url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(url)
            .then((res)=>{
                return res.json()
            })
            .then((data)=>{
                setData(data)
            })
    },[])

    let searchBar =  data.filter((e)=>{
        return e.id.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
    })

    // add to favorite

    function addToFav(id){
        if(!favorites.includes(id)){
            setFavorites(favorites.concat(id))
        }
    }







    function openModalFunc(id) {
        setOpenModal(true);
        if(!modalArr.includes(id)) {
            setModalArr(modalArr.concat(id))
        }

    }

    function closeModalFunc(id) {
        setOpenModal(false);
        setModalArr([]);
    }


    let modalRender = data.filter(data => modalArr.includes(data.id));
    let favoriteRender = data.filter(data =>  favorites.includes(data.id))


    console.log(favoriteRender)


    return(
        <div>
            <Navbar input={input} setInput={setInput}/>
            <div className='general-info'>
                <h4>Coin</h4>
                <h4 className='p'>Price</h4>
                <h4 className='c'>Change</h4>
                <h4 className='mc'>Market Cap</h4>
                <h4 className='s'>Supply</h4>
            </div>
            <Modal addFavorite = {addToFav} modalArr={modalRender}   close = {closeModalFunc}  open = {openModal}/>
            {searchBar.map((e)=>(
                    <div
                        onClick={()=>{
                            openModalFunc(e.id);
                        }}
                        className='all_coins_wrapper'>
                        <div className='coins-wrapper'>
                            <div className='coins-label'>

                                <img src={e.image} alt=""/>
                                <div className='general_info'>
                                    <div>{e.name}</div>
                                    <div>{e.symbol.toUpperCase()}</div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <p className='price-main'>${e.current_price}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className='left-part'>

                            <p className='change'>{e.price_change_percentage_24h}</p>
                            <div className='marcap'>{e.market_cap}</div>
                            <div className='circ'>{e.circulating_supply}</div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                )
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

SECOND ONE :
`

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./navbar";
import MainPage from "./home";

export default function FavoriteCrypto({favorite}){


    return(
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to import these variable '

```
    let favoriteRender = data.filter(data =>  favorites.includes(data.id))
```

from the first component to the second one in order to display on the second page the favoirite coins'

I tried to copy paste the code from the first component to the second component and to import the variable, but that didnt work. I am using react for a week now.So sorry if this question is already ask.But I cant solve this issue.

Comment: [Try to read the docs on passing props](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to export that variable in order to pass data between components. You can use props in-order to do so.

Here is the link to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

And here is an example of doing so:

```
// COMPONENT
const MyNameComponent = (props) => <h1>{props.name}</h1>;

// USAGE
const App = () => {
 const name = "John Doe";

 return <MyNameComponent name={name} />
}
```

As a solution to your problem could be:

```
<FavoriteCrypto favourite={favouriteRender} />
```

and using it inside the component to display it. You can align the data according to your wish. Read the docs for more info .